# Cycles CUDA issues in Google Colab when rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I am trying to render a scene on Google Colab but I keep getting the following error:

```
Blender 2.93.5 (hash a791bdabd0b2 built 2021-10-06 06:26:10) 
Read blend: /gdrive/MyDrive/BlenderRenders/appearing.blend 
Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error) 
Refer to the Cycles GPU rendering documentation for possible solutions: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html 
Fra:1 Mem:110.24M (Peak 110.27M) | Time:00:00.26 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene | Initializing Error: Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error) 
Invalid value in cuCtxDestroy(cuContext) (device_cuda_impl.cpp:252) 
Blender quit
```

The Colab worked fine a month or two ago, but for some reason is not working now.

The file was created in v2.93.5.

While it is possible for me to render this using CPU, it would be very slow to render 300 2048x2048 256 sample frames.